# Is it possible in git to have sub project folder permission managment

Tags: git

I am new to Git, so this is really a newbie question.

Is it possible to use a permission model on Git folders.
So one can have different sub projects,  and invite others to only have access to certain folder parts of a project. In this case i'm using my private repo; when one has setup Sourcetree
(i'm using SourceTree client)

Comment: Don't know how well SourceTree does with submodules, but those are  what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to setup within one repository. Git wasn't designed for closed-source software. If I were you, I would split the project into private and public part (no interleaving across the directory structure) and join the two parts by using some build tool.

You haven't mentioned the programming language. This would be language dependent. Also you may look into git sub-modules, although I would recommend the approach mentioned above.

Comment: Mainly its C# and C++

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can only separate them into different repositories. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475). Each repository should have **only one unique** permission configuration.